# Subir jsp en cpanel

Tags: jsp, cpanel

Buen día, tengo un sistemita web que desarrolle en jsp, he trabajado mucho haciendo este tipo de sistemas de practica en la universidad, pero lamentablemente es mi primera vez que voy a subir uno ya en la vida real y en linea.

tengo un dominio y un hosting contratado, me han dado acceso a un cpanel para subir mi sistema y que se pueda ver online.

logro subir el sistema con exito, pero a la hora de ir a mi web index, lo que me sale es todo el codigo fuente de la pagina y no el diseño que deberia de traducir el servidor.

lo curioso es que si le quito a mi jsp index un codigo de java, el sitio web sale perfectamente, pero se lo vuelvo a poner y se me vuelve a guindar.

se que el error esta en el codigo java, pero en netbeans me funciona perfecto.

Comment: cual es tu servidor hosting? y cual es tu servidor local?

Answer (score 0):

¿lograste resolver el tema ?

Por defecto estoy entiendo que el cpanel no viene instalado el servicio de Apache Tomcat y lo servlets para que puedan trabajar con la tecnologia java web jsp,tambien estoy teniendo el mismo caso en estos momentos, eh investigado y cpanel te da la guia para que puedas instalar estos servicios que te comento,adjunto link de referencia.

[cpanel y jsp](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/cpanel-tomcat-jsp-and-servlets-guide.282922/)

Donde detallan que tienes que ingresar al WHM’s  http://tudominio:2086 (puerto no seguro)
para eso tienes que tener el usuario y clave para que puedas acceder a ese servicio donde podras instalar lo que te comento lineas arriba.

Comment: Estoy frito, no se como hacerlo